# How would you work out this integral as a series?

Tags: integration

The integral is:

$$f(a) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x e^{-a^2 x^2}}{\tanh(x)}dx$$

which seems to converge for all $a>0$. But I don't know how to get a sense of the function $f(a)$ such as writing it as a convergent series. The usual Taylor series has infinity for each term. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I believe (using answers below) that when $a$ is close to zero we have (doing a substitution):

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{a^2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x e^{-x^2}}{\tanh (x/a)}dx$$

But using $\tanh(x/a)\rightarrow\operatorname{sign}(x)$ as $a\rightarrow 0^+$. So the above should become:
$$f(a) \approx \frac{2}{a^2}\int\limits_{0}^\infty x e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{1}{a^2}$$

So that gives the behaviour of $f(a)$ when $a$ is small. But I don't know how to give extra terms. (Also not sure if this is mathematically correct). From numerical calculations I find that near $0$,
$$
f(a)\approx \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{\pi^6}{6} - \frac{\pi^4 }{60}a^2+\frac{\pi^6 }{252}a^4+... = \frac{1}{a^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_{2n} a^{2n}\pi^{2n}}{n!}
$$
although apparently this doesn't converge?

**Comment**

The answers below are two asymptotic series depending on whether $a$ is small or large. These give good approximations if we truncate the summation before begins to diverge. In the mid-range, when $a^2=1/\pi$, these two sums become term-by-term equal and the closest the truncated sum get to the true answer of $f(1/\sqrt{\pi})$ is to about 1% error.  Using both these sums, we can know any value to within about 1%-2% error, and if $a$ is small or large then much more accurately.

Comment: Just from calculations it seems like a good approximation when $a$ is close to zero is $f(a)\approx 1.6 + 1/a^2$. (Just putting values like $a=1/1000$ into Wolfram alpha.

Comment: Your conjectured result is correct, up to a missing $\pi^{2n} $ - I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Taylor series exists in powers of $1/a$:
$$f(a) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x e^{-a^2 x^2}}{\tanh x}\,dx=a^{-2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{-x^2}\,\text{cotanh}\, (x/a)\,dx$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2 n} B_{2 n}   \,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2 n)!a^{2 n+1}},$$
with $B_{2n}$ the [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

---

To assess whether this asymptotic series is useful for $a\gtrsim 1$, below I plot the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{10}$, so the first eleven terms, for $a=1,2,3\ldots 10$ (blue data points), and compare with a numerical evaluation of the integral (blue curve).

[image]

Comment: Good stuff. Is it convergent? If range of convergence is $1/|a|<R$ for some $R$ it could mean that is doesn't converge near $a=0$.

Comment: Also in terms of  series of $_1F_1$ hypergeometric functions $$f(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2(1-2^{2n-1})\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!\,|a|^{2n+1}}\cdot\,_1F_1(n+1/2;1/2;1/(4a^2))$$

Comment: Alas the power series in powers of $1/a^2$
is only an asymptotic expansion at infinity;
it does not converge for any $a$.  [That is to be expected, because
the series was obtained by integrating termwise the Taylor expansion of
$\tanh x$ about $x=0$, and this Taylor expansion converges only for $|x| < \pi/2$
(the distance from $x=0$ to the nearest complex pole), whereas
the integral is over all real $x$.]

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Is that a convergent sum for all $a$?

Comment: I don't see how @JorgeZuniga 's series agrees with the integral; for example, for $a=5$ that sum gives 0.2006, while the correct value is 0.3568.

Comment: @Carlo_Beenakker. I will check if I missed something. All series, Michael's, yours and mine are asymptotic series as it can be seen if $B_{2n}$ is set in terms of Riemann's $ζ(2n)$.

Comment: I've checked it. Formula is formally correct. It was obtained by setting $\coth(x)=\cosh(x)\,csch(x)$, expanding $csch(x)$ as a formal power series and using CAS Mathematica to get even moments $\int_0^\infty x^{2n}\,\exp(-a^2 x^2)\cdot\,\cosh(x)\,dx$ that are expressed as $\,_1F_1$ hypergeometric functions.  This is an intrinsicly bad behaved divergent series whose antilimit is the integral and, as Carlo Beenakker has found, it is not useful for direct numerical evaluation.

Answer (score 12):

To obtain the series in $a$, separate off the leading term proportional to $1/a^2 $ and expand the Gaussian instead of the hyperbolic cotangent:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(a)&=& 2\int_{0}^{\infty } dx\, x \ e^{-a^2 x^2 } \left[ \coth x -1 +1 \right] \\
&=& 2\int_{0}^{\infty } dx\, x \ e^{-a^2 x^2 }+
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-a^2)^{n}}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} dx\, x^{2n+1} [\coth x -1] \\
&=& \frac{1}{a^2 } + 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-a^2)^{n}}{n!} \frac{ (-1)^n \pi^{2n+2} B_{2n+2} }{2n+2} \\
&=& \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{a^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(\pi a)^{2n} B_{2n} }{n!} \\
&=& \frac{1}{a^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(\pi a)^{2n} B_{2n} }{n!}
\end{eqnarray}
Also this is only an asymptotic expansion - the Bernoulli numbers diverge more rapidly than $n!$ at large $n$.

Comment: Wow. I take it the coth x integral is just one you have to know. I take it also it's an asymptotic sum as someone else mentioned. ( I tried it out numerically and it seems to diverge for all x after long enough - although that could just be machine errors).

Comment: Well, I suppose there's no reason an integral *should* have a representation as a convergent series, I guess.

Comment: @zooby - Since $\coth x -1 = 1/(e^{2x} -1)$, the integral is one of the pretty standard ones that lead to Bernoulli polynomials ...

Comment: By truncating the expansion of $e^{-a^2x^2}$ with a remainder term having known bound, you should be able to do that for the final expansion too. Then you will have rigorous bounds on $f(a)$.